# SQL Server CE - Inheritance mapping - column cannot containt null values exception

Tags: linq, sql-server-ce

I am designing a simple db. Two tables were quite similar so I've used inheritance mapping technique.

```
[Table]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "P", Type = typeof(ATable),
        IsDefault = true)]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "E", Type = typeof(BTable))]
public class ATable: TableBase
{

        [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
        public string DiscKey;

        private int _Id;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set
            {
                if (_Id != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _Id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

       ....

}

public class BTable : ATable
{

    private int _Property;
    [Column]
    public int Property
    {
        get { return _Property; }
        set
        {
            if (_Property!= value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Property");
                _DeviceDetailsId = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Property");
            }
        }
    }

   ...
}

//DBDATACONTEXT

public class DBDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public DBDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
        public Table<ATable> As;
    }
```

when I try:

```
var db = DBDataContext("Data Source=isostore:/xDB.sdf;Password='testpass';");

var atable = new ATable();

db.As.InsertOnSubmit(atable);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

I get an exception: The column cannot contain null values. [ Column name = Property,Table name = ATable]

What's wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row on the table will always contains all the properties of all the inherited entities... so marking child columns(properties) with CanBeNull = true will solve the problem.